# Retaining NSMutableArray values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am setting NSMutableArray values on class2. Array is filled and retained while executing class2 functions. Problem is that I need to switch to class1 and then recall function from class2. Then, array is empty!
I think that problem comes from method I use to call class2 function, when allocating again... How to solve it? thank you

```
class2 *theInstance = [class2 alloc];

[theInstance saveFilesNews:llistaArxius:folderType:originType];
```

Comment: how you are switching to class 1(by popping up or some other way.) and can you add some more code.

Comment: same method to switch to class1. I can post as code as necessary but I don't know if will help or which part exactly...

Comment: if you are popping from Class 2 to Class 1, then you will not able to do this. As all the objects of Class 2 will be released by that time. Are you doing this? If this is the case then you need to pass that value to Class 1 before popping.

Comment: Retain the mutable array somewhere.  (And remember to release it when you're done with it.)  Or switch to ARC.

Comment: @RIP, I am doing this! but thought that was other option :(

Comment: @Hot Licks I am retaining the array and also using ARC

Comment: You can make an array in CLass 1 and from class 2 you can set that for Class1.As i think you are pushing Class 2 on Class 1, so from Class2, Class 1 will be easily accessible.

Comment: @RIP done as you suggested and working! Thank you, please post it as an answer

Comment: @Jaume great...will post this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are popping from Class 2 to Class 1, then you will not able to do this. As all the objects of Class 2 will be released by that time. If this is the case then you need to pass that value to Class 1 before popping.

You can make an array in CLass 1 and from class 2 you can set that for Class1.As i think you are pushing Class 2 on Class 1, so from Class2, Class 1 will be easily accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize theInstance. First of all, your naming conventions are poor. A class, such as class2, should be capitalized, i.e. Class2. Secondly, you need a more descriptive name than Class2. The real issue is that you aren't getting a prepared instance back from the first line of code. You're allocating enough space in memory for Class2, but it is never initialized. Additionally, if you have an array in Class2 that you fill with some objects and then in Class1 you want to replace or access those objects in some way, then the array needs to be a property of Class2, ***AND*** you need to make sure you are accessing the same reference of the Class2 instance that already exists. If you alloc/init a new Class2 instance, you'll have an empty array.